# C: array of void*

Tags: c, void-pointers

I'm using `openCV` and need some callback function. these `callback` function just accept limited parameters. So, if I need more variables for those function, I must make a global variables and turn it around between functions.

For example, here is the callback function :

```
    void mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param);
// params : addition parameter, and just one, I need more parameters for this callback.
// but cannot, so make global variable.
```

And because I shouldn't do that (make global variable), so I decided to make array of `(void*)` but I afraid C cannot make this, because size of each members can be different.

My question is : can we make array of (void*), and if not, how can I overcome my problem : use callback function and don't need to make global variable.

Thanks :)

Comment: Create a struct with all of your data in it and then cast it to `void*`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262012/array-of-void-pointers-in-c

Comment: @LuchianGrigore ah, yes, we know the size of (void*). I'm sorry. but, I still cannot use as : `(void*) a[];`

Comment: a pointer is alway 32bit size in a 32bit computer, so `int *`, `char *`, `void *` is same size. Just try: `void *a[SIZE]`

Comment: @BìnhNguyên, that's not necessarily true. Only thing guaranteed is that any pointer type can be converted to `void*` and back again.

Comment: @eq: `int *` (or whatever which is 32bit pointers) can be converted to others too (in 32bit platform), but need a cast

Comment: GWW is right.  @hqt, the void* is not indicating an array.  Its referencing some struct that you define and pass to the function.  You pass the pointer to struct as a void*.  In your callback, cast back to the "known" type (warning, this can be dangerous since passing a pointer to the wrong type will cause weirdness, but this is the C way to do this).

Comment: There are no extra specifications regarding any "32-bit platforms" in the C standard. Conversion between unrelated pointer types (such as `int*` and `short*`) results in (IIRC) implementation-specific behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define a `struct` that is capable of holding all necessary values and pass its address as the `param` argument:

```
struct my_type
{
    int i;
    char c;
};

void my_mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    struct my_type* t = param;
}
```

Not sure what the registration mechanism is but you need to ensure that the lifetime of the object pointed to by `param` is valid for the calling period of the callback function:

```
struct my_type* mouse_param = malloc(sizeof(*mouse_param));
mouse_param->i = 4;
mouse_param->c = 'a';

register_mouse_callback(my_mouse_callback, mouse_param);
```

Specifically, don't do this:

```
{
    struct my_type mouse_param = { 4, 'a' };
    register_mouse_callback(my_mouse_callback, &mouse_param);
} /* 'mouse_param' would be a dangling pointer in the callback. */
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make array of `void *` because a pointer has a definite size, however, you cannot use these pointers without casting them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a void* that points to a struct with your parameters. In the callback function you cast this type (void*) back to the struct* with your params like this:

```
typedef struct {
  int event;
  int x;
  int y;
  int flags;
} params;

void mouse_callback(void *data) {
   params* param  = (params*) data;
   // now you can use param->x or param->y to access the parameters
}
```

To pass parameters you need create a paramstruct and cast its address to (void*):

```
paramstruct myparams;
myparams.x = 2;
myparams.y = 1;

mouse_callback( (void*) &myparams );
```

Comment: Right... (void*) &params, when calling the function is not needed. But it clarifies what it happening, thought.But the cast "(paramsstruct*) data" is needed... or is at least better written code ;-)

Comment: Neither cast is necessary, nor clarifies anything at all. The implicit conversion rules are and should be clear to any C programmer and it's obvious what the type of local variable `param` will be anyway.

Comment: I'm very sure you'll get some nerving warnings when compiling using "gcc -Wall"; Good coding style also means to write code in a way, that a compiler accepts it without warnings.

Comment: I'm rather sure you won't, as long as it's C you're compiling.

Comment: You are right! Tested without explicit casts, saved&compiled from .c-File. No warnings were producted, even using -Wall. Ergo: You'll never know everything ;-) Thanks for that lesson...